# How to use a for loop to access elements in a non-indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, associative-array

I'm trying to get text from multi array, I got 1st and 2nd array but could not to get text from 3rd array.

You can see my code here:

```
<div class="personTools">
    <ul>
        <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($toolsMenu["TOOLS_MENU"]) ; $i++){
        ?>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <li><?php echo $toolsMenu["TOOLS_MENU"][$i]; ?> <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <?php
                    for ($d = 0; $d < count ($toolsMenu["TOOLS_MENU"][$i]); $d++) {
                ?>
                        <li><?php echo $toolsMenu["TOOLS_MENU"][$i][$d]; ?> </li>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my array here:

```
$toolsMenu = array(
    "TOOLS_MENU" => array(
            "تجربة 1" => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
            "تجربة 2" => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
            "تجربة 3" => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
            "تجربة 4" => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
     )
);
```

My question is: Why I'm getting this message?

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\mazadi\tmpl\html.tpl on line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `foreach()` is given then why to use `for()`:-

```
<div class="personTools">
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($toolsMenu["TOOLS_MENU"] as $key=> $toolsM){
        ?>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <li><?php echo $key; ?> <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <?php
                    foreach ($toolsM as $tools) {
                ?>
                        <li><?php echo $tools; ?> </li>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note:- Try to avoid `for` loop as much as possible, if you are able to handle things with `foreach()`because `foreach()` take care of indexes itself, while `for` loop doesn't.